# Detect unused/non-existent keys in git config

Tags: git

My global `.gitconfig` is very long. Some of the keys are obviously invalid, like typos. Other options I'm not sure about.

Is there a command that will identify or remove unused keys? These have valid *names* but don't actually identify any configuration that git knows about, or are duplicated within the file.

Example:

```
[merge]
    stan = false # typo!
    conflictstyle=diff3 
    conflictstyle=diff3 # duplicate!
```

Answer (score 2):

Who says they do not "identify" any configuration that git knows about? Basically some tool or manually installed subcommand or hook script or enriched bash prompt could interpret this key. So there is no way to remove invalid keys as there is no way to know which keys are invalid, besides duplicates.

Comment: Well, I says so (I added them, and mostly they're obvious typos). But if it's common for other scripts to use custom git config keys, then I guess my question should be about detecting "vanilla" git config keys, and I realize why that wouldn't be a super useful tool.